# Issue when passing data through segue in swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue

This is the code of a Tip Calculator app that has a Settings View where I select a Default Tip Rate, the problem is that when I launch the app and I begin to enter an amount in the text field the tipPercentageLabel sets to "0.0%" until I select a percentage using the slider, also when I go to the settings view I set the tipRate to a percentage for example 30% the I go back to the main view controller and it is like when I launch the app. If you want to test it here is the link to download the project [Link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb8zwkz51ipinp0/Tip%20Calc%20Pro.xcodeproj.zip?dl=0
Here is the instructions that Codepath University give me for this project that decides who enters to their Curse http://courses.codepath.com/snippets/intro_to_ios/prework.md
[image]

**VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, SettingsDelegate {
// Inputs
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
//Labels
@IBOutlet weak var TipPercentageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPersonLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tipAmountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalBillLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var billPerPersonLabel: UILabel!
//Slider & Stepper
@IBOutlet weak var tipSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var personsStepper: UIStepper!
//Variables
var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") ?? 0.20
var numberOfPerson:Int = 1
let numberFormatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tipAmountLabel.text = "$0.00"
    totalBillLabel.text = "Bill Total"
    billPerPersonLabel.text = "$0.00"
    numberOfPersonLabel.text = "1"
    self.amountTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print("DefaultTipRate")
    var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate")
    TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func setupContainer() {


    tipSlider.minimumValue = 0
    tipSlider.maximumValue = 100
    tipSlider.value = 20
    tipSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderTipChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    personsStepper.minimumValue = 1
    personsStepper.maximumValue = 30
    personsStepper.value = 1
    personsStepper.addTarget(self, action: "sliderPersonChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    amountTextField.text = ""

    refreshCalculation()

}

@IBAction func OnEditingFieldBill(sender: AnyObject) {

    refreshCalculation()
}

func refreshCalculation() {

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    if let amount = numberFormatter.numberFromString(amountTextField.text!) as? Double {

        let tipAmount = amount * tipPercentage
        let totalBill = amount + tipAmount
        let billPerPerson = totalBill / Double(numberOfPerson)
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        tipAmountLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipAmount)
        totalBillLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalBill)
        billPerPersonLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(billPerPerson)

    } else {

        tipAmountLabel.text = "-"
        totalBillLabel.text = "-"
        billPerPersonLabel.text = "-"
    }

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.PercentStyle
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage)

   numberOfPersonLabel.text = "\(numberOfPerson)"

} 

@IBAction func sliderTipChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    tipPercentage = Double(round(tipSlider.value)) / 100
    refreshCalculation()
}


@IBAction func StepperPersonChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfPerson = Int(round(personsStepper.value))
    refreshCalculation()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let SettingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController {
        SettingsViewController.delegate = self
        refreshCalculation()
            }
        }
func tipPercentageChanged(newValue: Double) {
    TipPercentageLabel.text = "\(newValue)%"
    tipPercentage = newValue
    refreshCalculation()
}
}
```

**SETTINGS VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
protocol SettingsDelegate{
func tipPercentageChanged(newValue : Double)
}
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tipControl: UISegmentedControl!
var tipRates: Double?
var destName : String!
var delegate :SettingsDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func DefaultRate(sender: AnyObject) {
    var tipRate = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
    tipRates = Double(tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex])
    delegate?.tipPercentageChanged(tipRates!)


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(tipRates!, forKey: "DefaultTipRate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}
```

Comment: You have to set the TipPercentageLabel value in the viewdidload which is set in the refreshCalculation function. I can see that on refreshCalculation is only called when there is an action performed on the OnEditingFieldBill.

Comment: @Karlos Previously I set the following:

Comment: @Karlos Var tipDisplay = tipPercentage * 100          tipPercentageLabel.text = "\(tipDisplay)%"

Comment: but it doesn't works

Comment: Hey try adding these two lines in viewdidload or viewWillAppear.

var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate")
TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage)

Comment: Okay @Karlos let me check if that works

Comment: If the DefaultRate is not set then check if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") == nil {
    //Set the tipPercentage value here
}

Comment: I try adding the two lines that you said in viewdidload and it still doing the same( I set a default tip rate then when I go back it just like when I opened the app), Where did you said to add "==nil"? In the line that you previously said to me?

Comment: In the viewWillAppear function. Also print the value of DefaultTipRate in the start of viewWillAppear.

Comment: It says "A value type 'Double' can never be nil"

Comment: Okay, Please comment the NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") == nil  for now and run the project. Can you add your sample code in the GitHub or DropBox? So I can run on my system and get back on this with a solution.

Comment: Yes Above I leave the dropbox link to download the code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb8zwkz51ipinp0/Tip%20Calc%20Pro.xcodeproj.zip?dl=0 @Karlos

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Karlos

Comment: I have dowloaded it, but it consist of only storyboard files.All other files are missing.

Comment: Thats true, my bad, give me one second I will upload it to dropbox

Comment: Here is @Karlos https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yt6jgeqo009rz1/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: sorry for the delay @Karlos

Comment: Hey, I have checked your code and found that the DefaultRate function in SettingsViewController never called even if you change the percentage in the slider. Try adding a breakpoint on the DefaultRate and change the value of default tip rate. It doesn't work.

Comment: Okay so that is what is causing this problem, I think I will need your help calling this function.

Comment: You said that it doesn't work?

Comment: Use this . 
@IBAction func changevalue(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        var tipRate = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
        
        
        
        tipRates = Double(tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex])
        delegate?.tipPercentageChanged(tipRates!)
        
        print("\(tipRates)")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(tipRates!, forKey: "DefaultTipRate")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
And set the event to "Value Changed"  it will work. I have tested it here

Comment: I will try, but what you said about breakpoints? Today I here about  breakpoints but I don't know exactly what they are and how to add them.

Comment: On tap of the bill rate you are multiplying the DefaultRate by 100. Why I didn't get it.

Comment: Whenever I set the value of Default rate and enter the value for bill amount. the default rate value is multiplied by 100 automatically.
Give me your mail id, I will send you the updated code.

Comment: Im trying to deal with the link that you send to me, and textLabel.text = "First Segment Selected";   in my case that would be?

Comment: Thanks, my email is yadiel458pr@gmail.com

Comment: Just replaced your DefaultRate IBAction with this @IBAction func changevalue(sender: UISegmentedControl) { var tipRate = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30] tipRates = Double(tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]) delegate?.tipPercentageChanged(tipRates!) print("(tipRates)") NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(tipRates!, forKey: "DefaultTipRate") NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() } and set the event to "Value Changed" it will work.

Comment: I have sent you a mail with updated code attached. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: A lot of thanks, as soon I run it I will let you know

Comment: Hey @Karlos I have to delete the viewWillAppear?

Comment: Its fine you can delete it.

Comment: Okay, did you run the app and it works as should be? , I run the app and I thinks it is multiplying the amount I put, in the tipPercentageLabel appear 2,000% and thousands %

Comment: Yes, it works and but I also saw that issue of multiplying the default rate.

Comment: Yes, did you identify what makes  this new issue?

Comment: Not yet. Sorry was busy with my other projects

Comment: In 'refreshCalculation' this TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage) is making change in the default rate. There is some issue in the numberFormatter.

Comment: @Karlos it is multiplying by 100, do you think is in the func setUpContainer() { , in that line I set the maximum value to 100

Comment: @Karlos Take a look at this please http://imgur.com/KwhoqxF